# Escuchar cambio de un elemento select, seteado dinámicamente

Tags: javascript

He probado lo siguiente, la función **addEventListener** escucha los cambios hechos de forma manual pero no escucha los cambios seteados al mismo select desde otra función.

```js
document.getElementById('boxnumeros').addEventListener('change', event => {
  if (event.target.id === 'numeros') { 
    console.log("Se cambio el elemento")
  }
});
function cambiar(){
  const opcion = 3;
  document.getElementById('numeros').value = opcion;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxnumeros">
  <select id="numeros">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="cambiar();">Cambiar</button>
```

Comment: El evento `onchange` solo se dispara por acciones del usuario. Sería conveniente que edites la pregunta para explicar exactamente lo que deseas hacer y poder proponer una solución.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```javascript
function val() {
    d = document.getElementById("numeros").value;
    console.log(d);
}

<select id="numeros" onchange="val()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```